# Quarkus endpoints to download and upload json file

Tags: java, json, rest, quarkus

I have to create endpoints to  download and upload group configuration as a json file. In database the configuration is saved as a json object. It should be converted to json file if the user want to download the configuration. If user upload config file it should be converted to json object, so it can be saved in database.

```
@GET
@Path("group/config/{groupId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response downloadGroupConfig(@PathParam("groupId") String groupId) {
     // the group config comes from database and should be converted here to config.json file and then added to response      
     // something like: return Response.ok(config.json).build();
}
```

and for upload config file

```
@POST
@Path("group/config/{groupId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadConfigFile(@RequestBody //(contains config.json), @PathParam("groupId") String groupId ){
     // convert config.json to json object and save it in database
}
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what the problem is. Can you clarify please?

Comment: So i want that the response is a .json file. E.g config.json

Answer (score 1):

For the download you can do something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("group/config/{groupId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response downloadGroupConfig(@PathParam("groupId") String groupId) {
    return Response.ok("{\"location\":  \"German\"}")
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"config.json\"")
            .build()
}
```

For the upload part, you probably want to use Multipart support, see [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#multipart).

Comment: How can i write the json object to .json file? E.g the json object `{"location:  "German"}` to config.json